# Converting Long Text with HTML Tags to another Rich Text Field

Tags: visual-workflow, html, richtextarea, long-text-area

I've run into a unique situation converting values from a 'long text' field into a 'rich text' field.

Our SFDC instance is integrated with another tool ('Tool X') that sends data back into Salesforce. In 'Tool X', certain values are displayed as rich text fields with formatting (e.g. bolded headers, numbered lists, bulleted lists, etc). Unfortunately, 'Tool X' CANNOT sync data into a rich text field. When the data syncs back into SFDC, it syncs back into a long text field with all HTML tags.

**Is it possible to parse out the HTML tags here? Or, perhaps even better, is there somewhere (Flow?) where we can access the HTML code on rich text field and use these values?**

**Example (Long Text):** *this is how the field is syncing today*

```
<p><span style=font-size:9px><strong>Header Goes Here</strong> <br />

<strong><em>Revised Jan 2022</em></strong><br />

<strong> </strong><br />

<strong>1/ Point 1:</strong><br />

Text Text Text<br />

<strong>a). Example A</strong></span></p>
<ul>

            <li><span style=font-size:9px>Example 1 goes here.</span></li>

            <li><span style=font-size:9px>Example 2 goes there. <span></li>

</ul>
```

**Example (Rich Text) -** *this is how the field value SHOULD look*

**Header Goes Here**
***Revised Jan 2022***

**1/ Point 1:**

Text Text Text

**a). Example A**

- Example 1 goes here
- Example 2 goes there

Comment: as an experiment, use dataloader or developer console to see what the RTF looks like and compare it to the long text field; this will tell you whether a simple field copy will suffice

Comment: Do you want it displayed in a rich text field with all the formatting, or do you want it displayed in a long text field without the HTML?